# wxWidgets-how to add scrollbars in ListBox created by comboctrl widget in wxpython

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I have created dropdown list using wxcomboctrl.

```
self.Worker = wx.combo.ComboCtrl(self, -1, size=(250, -1), style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN)
self.testWorkloadComboCtrl = self.ListCtrlComboPopup()
self.worker.SetPopupControl(self.workerComboCtrl)


class ListCtrlComboPopup(wx.ListCtrl, wx.combo.ComboPopup):

    def __init__(self):
        self.PostCreate(wx.PreListCtrl())

        # Also init the ComboPopup base class.
        wx.combo.ComboPopup.__init__(self)


    def AddItem(self, txt):
        for t in txt:
            self.InsertStringItem(self.GetItemCount(), t)


    def OnMotion(self, evt):

        item, flags = self.HitTest(evt.GetPosition())
        if item >= 0:
            self.Select(item)
            self.curitem = item


    def OnLeftDown(self, evt):

        self.value = self.curitem
        self.Dismiss()


    # The following methods are those that are overridable from the
    # ComboPopup base class.

    def Init(self):
        """ This is called immediately after construction finishes.  You can
        use self.GetCombo if needed to get to the ComboCtrl instance. """

        self.value = -1
        self.curitem = -1


    def Create(self, parent):
        """ Create the popup child control. Return True for success. """

        wx.ListCtrl.Create(self, parent,
                       style=wx.LC_LIST|wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL|wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMotion)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnLeftDown)

        return True


    def GetControl(self):
        """ Return the widget that is to be used for the popup. """

        return self

    def SetStringValue(self, val):
        """ Called just prior to displaying the popup, you can use it to
    'select' the current item. """

        idx = self.FindItem(-1, val)

        if idx != wx.NOT_FOUND:
            self.Select(idx)


    def GetStringValue(self):
        """ Return a string representation of the current item. """

        if self.value >= 0:
            return self.GetItemText(self.value)

        return ""


    def OnPopup(self):
        """ Called immediately after the popup is shown. """

        wx.combo.ComboPopup.OnPopup(self)


    def OnDismiss(self):
        " Called when popup is dismissed. """

        wx.combo.ComboPopup.OnDismiss(self)
```

The dropdown displaying the items like 2 or 3 columns with horizontal scrollbar.

But I wish to display a single list of items with both horizontal and vertical scroll bars.

I searched for the comboctrl properties but still not clear about comboctrl.

Can anyone suggest me on this.

Comment: Have you tried using wxFormBuilder https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxformbuilder/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `wx.LC_REPORT` style instead of `wx.LC_LIST`.  You'll also need to create the column(s) like any other use of `wx.LC_REPORT` styled `wx.ListCtrls`.

Comment: thanks for the reply.I have no idea of how to create column with comboctrl list pop up..Can you tell me an example for single list.

Comment: When you create the listctrl you need to use `AddColumn`, just like you would if you were using a `wx.ListCtrl` by itself without the comboctrl.